# How to declare object in array variable?

Tags: javascript

How do I declare object in an array variable. It shows the below error

> "TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined"

This is the code:

```
let data = []
data[0].name = "john"
```

Comment: `data  = [ { name: "john" } ]`

Answer (score 2):

You would need to declare the first element of the array to be an object, before you can set properties on that object.

One of the ways of doing so would be:

```
let data = [];
data[0] = {};
data[0].name = "john";
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting an error because `data` is an empty array and hence `data` array does not have any element at position `0`. Hence when you try to access it like `data[0]` (*which you can check in console*), you will get `undefined`. Any trying to set a new `name` property to `undefined` gives `Cannot set property 'name' of undefined"` error. You can fix this issue in many ways, one of the ways is to just push the new object like:

```js
let data = []
data.push({ name : "john"});
console.log(data)
```

Or, you can also try to declare `data[0]` to an empty object first, so that you can assign any new property to it after that like:

```js
let data = [];
data[0] = {};
console.log(typeof data[0]);  // This is not undefined anymore
data[0].name = "john";
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

That would be

> let data =[]; data[0] = {"name":"john"}